# Selecting features with values whose difference is greater than 20 in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, features, expression, select-by-attribute

I have a LineString layer and it's attribute table has two different fields. I want to select all features with a difference of  more than 20 between both fields.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are interested in the *absolute* difference between the two columns:

```
abs(col1-col2) > 20
```